# Magento 2.3.X - custom module UI components not loading

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui

The UI XML file:

> app/code/NewShop/NewModule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.container">
      <block class="NewShop\NewModule\Block\Cart\Ui" name="newshop-newmodule-cart-ui" template="NewShop_NewModule::cart/ui.phtml" after="checkout.cart.form">
        <arguments>
          <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="ui" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">NewShop_NewModule/js/cart</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="template" xsi:type="string">NewShop_NewModule/checkout/cart</item>
                </item>
              </item>
            </item>
          </argument>
        </arguments>
      </block>
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

These are the files I'm attempting to load:

> app/code/NewShop/NewModule/view/frontend/web/js/cart.js
>
> app/code/NewShop/NewModule/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart.html

But I get this error in browser console:

```
[ERROR] Failed to load the "NewShop_NewModule/js/cart" component. 
console-output-handler.js:34
```

My Questions are:

- Is there anything wrong in the XML code?
- Is Magento 2.3 different from Magento 2.1 on how it loads the UI components?

Comment: did you find any solution ????